# AppFrameWorkInfo and Pods_Runner are showing red in Xcode / Flutter: how to solve it?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I honestly don't know what to do anymore. I am getting the error:

```
Failed to package
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

[image]

And my `AppFrameworkInfo`
+
`Pods_Runner` is showing **red**.

When I check the Flutter documents, I already can see that it's not the same as how Flutter did it.

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ios-project-migration

What am I doing wrong here? I tried everything: removing and reinstalling pods and all other tips in other questions.

Anyone who could help here? I am really stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do:

```
flutter create .
```

You have to do this in your main project folder. Remove any ios folder if there is one and make sure you do the command with the dot.

Should work.